# Converting from a byte to a bit array to hexadecimal in c (pls help mi)

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation, serversocket, decoding

I'm currently working on a network socket programming task where I have to decode a message request, which is in the form :

```
uint8_t buffer[16] = {0xd8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab}
```

Read in using read():

```
uint8_t buffer[2048];     
read(conn->socketfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)
```

Now, I need to take the first hexadecimal byte 'd8', which is the binary 11011000, and extract the 1st FOUR bits of 1101 and retrieve the hexadecimal number of this - which is given by 0xD.

I'm struggling with the two parts of the problem:

1. Retrieving the 4 bits from the value d8
2. Converting the 4 bits back to a hexadecimal, ie. getting the value 0xD

Would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The lowest memory size software can manipulate is a byte. Even though you want to retrieve the first 4 bits, you are already presented with 0x0D. So the conversion again is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t first_hex_byte = buffer[0]; // 0xd8
uint8_t first_4bits = (buffer[0] >> 4) & 0xf; // 0xD
printf("%x\n", (int)first_4bits); // Print it as hex
```

But you have to ensure that wherever you are reading the data from the socket from, its sending in the expected Endian-ness. You can verify this by checking the buffer in a debugger and ensuring the buffer bytes are what you expect.

Comment: @MohithReddy endianness does not change the position of bits within the byte, but rather the position of bytes within a data type longer than one byte. Its best to change endianness in the protocol code that is aware of the structure of the packet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!